# validating a form then displaying the other hidden form using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, validation

i'm having a bit of a problem with my jquery code..i have two forms in my page..one displays when the user loads the page and the other is hidden(set to style="display:none;"). I want to fill out all the details in the first form and on clicking next, display the hidden form..problem is, the hidden form gets displayed on clicking the 'next' button even when the first form has no input..so i'm guessing i'm doing something wrong with the jquery validation code(i'm using the jQuery Validation plugin)..any help would be appreciated.thanks in advance

Here's how my code looks like:
    
    The DETAILS

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">    </script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.8/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<body>

<div class="item item1">
<form action="index.html" method="get" id = "form1">

<h1>The DETAILS</h1>
<p align="justify">Try our FREE landlord cost calculator and<br>
  discover the real cost of letting your property. <br>
   <input name="name"  type="text" placeholder="your name"class="required" />


  <br>

  <input name="email" type="text" placeholder="your email" class="required" />
  <br>

  <input name="phone" id="phone" type="text" placeholder="your phone no"  class="required" />
  <br>

  <input name="postcode" id="postcode" type="text" placeholder="postcode of property to let" class="required" />
  <br>

  <select name="bedrooms" id="bedrooms" placeholder="bedrooms" class="required" >

   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2" >2</option>
   <option value='' disabled selected="selected">Please Choose</option>
  </select> 
  <br>

  <input name="hearAbout" type="text" placeholder="where did your hear about us?" class="required" />
  <br>

   <button class="submit button1 " id = "next" name="submit" type="submit" value="next"><span class="next ">></span>next</button>
   </p>
   </form>



 </div>

   <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#form1").validate();
  });
  </script>


 <script>
 $("#form1").submit(function() {
  /* AJAX calls and insertion into #form2 */
  $("#form2").show();
  return false;
  });
  </script>   



  <div class="item item2">


 <form action="calculation.php" method="post" id = "form2"style="display:none;"> 
 <h1>The Income</h1>
 <label> Estimated monthly rent:&pound; </label>     <input name="rent" id="rent"    type="text" /><hr>
 THE COSTS            STEP 3 <hr>
 Agents Commission:  <select name="commission" id="commission">
 <option value="10%">10%</option>

 <option value="12%" selected="selected">12%</option>
 </select> <hr>
 Estimated Setup Fees:&pound; <input id="fees" name="fees" type="text" /><hr>

 How many weeks in the year do you estimate <br>that your property will<br> be    vacant/empty?<input name="weeks" type="text" /><hr>
 <button class="submit button2" name="submit" type="submit" value="calculate"><span   class="next">></span>calculate</button>
 </form>

 </div>
```

Comment: where are the arguments for jQuery form validation? here's the link http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate

Comment: i use the attribute 'submit' in the button tag for the first form

Comment: I understand that but where are the fields that you validating? where are the rules?

Comment: in form1, from the name placeholder to the hear about us placeholder

Comment: yes i know that. but where are the rules for validation in jQuery? your not maximizing the plugin. Does it make sense? read my answer

Answer (score 0):

your submit action should validate on submitting the first form and then show other form. Please try below code.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#form1").submit(function() {
     $("#form1").validate();
  /* AJAX calls and insertion into #productionForm */
    $("#form2").show();
    return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Hey Ganesh..thanks for your response but using your code above yields the same result..clicking the next button causes the hidden form to display EVEN with NO data in the input fields

Answer (score 0):

Try using jQuery Form Plugin: http://malsup.com/jquery/form/

Put this in the  section:

```
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script>
```

and then modify your script with ajaxForm:

```
<script>
$("#form1").ajaxForm(function() {
/* AJAX calls and insertion into #productionForm */
$("#form2").show();
return false;
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Elena for your reply but your stated script seems to have disabled the 'next' button

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I am talking about on my comment Harun Thuo :

```
$(".selector").validate({
  rules: {
    // simple rule, converted to {required:true}
    name: "required",
    // compound rule
    email: {
      required: true,
      email: true
    }
  },
  submitHandler: function(form) {
    // do other things for a valid form
    form.submit();
    $("#form2").show();
      return false;
    });
  }
});
```

**You can do the submission here. Read the documentation. You can also control the error placement.**

http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate